# Django. How to locate slow tests?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

How to locate slow django tests? How to locate tests, on which test runner can 'stuck'? Do you know any good custom django test runners, that can provide more detailed information on test performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [nose](http://readthedocs.org/docs/nose/en/latest/). Plenty of [tutorials](http://webamused.wordpress.com/2010/04/07/tutorial-testing-efficiently-with-nose-nose-exclude-and-django-nose/) available on installing it along with Django. To get a high level overview of testing time, look into the [pinocchio](http://darcs.idyll.org/~t/projects/pinocchio/doc/) nose extensions, specifically the stopwatch one.

Answer (score 11):

You can get Django to print the tests it's running with:

```
./manage.py test -v 3
```

This will print the name of the test, run it, then print "ok".  So you can figure out which test is slow.

Answer (score 6):

To identify slow tests, you would measure the duration it takes for each test to run and define a threshold of what slow means to you.

By default, Django's test runner does not show detailed timing information. You could use an alternative test runner, some of which will show timing data for test runs.

However, you could easily cook your own, as Django uses Python's unittest facilities, which are well documented and can be extended.

The following code can be found in one file here:
https://gist.github.com/cessor/44446799736bbe801dc5565b28bfe58b

To run tests, Django uses a [`DiscoverRunner`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5c93a84f44054034f495267ff2400a5de69a4fc1/django/test/runner.py#L628) (which wraps Python's [`TestRunner`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TextTestRunner)). The runner will discover testcases from your project structure by convention. Cases are collected in a [`TestSuite`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TextTestRunner) and executed. For each test method, a [`TestResult`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestSuite) will be created which is then used to communicate the result to the developer.

To measure how long it takes for a test to run, you may exchange the `TestResult` for a custom class:

```py
import unittest
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner

class StopwatchTestResult(unittest.TextTestResult):
    ...

class StopwatchTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    def get_resultclass(self):
        return StopwatchTestResult
```

In this example, the code above is placed in a Django app called `example` in a module called `testrunner.py`. To execute it, invoke Django's test command like this:

```bash
$ python manage.py test --testrunner=example.testrunner.StopwatchTestRunner -v 2
```

The `StopwatchTestResult` can be made to register timing data:

```py
import time
...
class StopwatchTestResult(unittest.TextTestResult):
    """
    Times test runs and formats the result
    """

    # Collection shared between all result instaces to calculate statistics
    timings = {}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.start = 0
        self.stop = 0
        self.elapsed = 0

    def startTest(self, test):
        self.start = time.time()
        super().startTest(test)

    def stopTest(self, test):
        super().stopTest(test)
        self.stop = time.time()
        self.elapsed = self.stop - self.start
        self.timings[test] = self.elapsed

    def getDescription(self, test):
        """
        Format test result with timing info
        e.g. `test_add (module) [0.1s]`
        """
        description = super().getDescription(test)
        return f'{description} [{self.elapsed:0.4f}s]'
```

For each test method, `TestResult.startTest` is called and registers a time stamp. The duration of each test run is calculated in `TestResult.stopTest`.

When the verbosity is increased, the description is printed, which allows you to format the timing data:

```
test_student_can_retract_their_request_commit (person.tests.test_view_new.test_view_person_new.NewViewTest) [0.0080s] ... ok
test_student_can_see_their_request_status (person.tests.test_view_new.test_view_person_new.NewViewTest) [0.0121s] ... ok
test_student_can_submit_request (person.tests.test_view_new.test_view_person_new.NewViewTest) [0.0101s] ... ok
```

To identify slow tests, you can either eyeball the solution or use a systematic approach:

```
class StopwatchTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._stats = kwargs['stats']

    @classmethod
    def add_arguments(cls, parser):
        DiscoverRunner.add_arguments(parser)
        parser.add_argument(
            "--stats",
            action="store_true",
            help="Print timing statistics",
        )

    def run_tests(self, test_labels, extra_tests=None, **kwargs):
        super().run_tests(test_labels, extra_tests, **kwargs)
        if self._stats:
            StopwatchTestResult.print_stats()

    def get_resultclass(self):
        ...
```

This test runner adds a new option to the test command. The command will print additional statistics, when the `--stats` option is set:

```bash
$ python manage.py test --testrunner=example.testrunner.StopwatchTestRunner -v 2 --stats
```

The actual calculation and output are performed in  `StopwatchTestResult.print_stats()`. It is implemented as a class method because it refers to data belonging to all TestResults:

```py
import statistics 

class StopwatchTestResult(unittest.TextTestResult):
    ...
    @classmethod
    def print_stats(cls):
        """
        Calculate and print timings

        These data are likely skewed, as is normal for reaction time data,
        therefore mean and standard deviation are difficult to interpret.
        Thus, the IQR is used to identify outliers.
        """
        timings = StopwatchTestResult.timings.values()
        count = len(timings)
        mean = statistics.mean(timings)
        stdev = statistics.stdev(timings)
        slowest = max(timings)
        q1, median, q3 = statistics.quantiles(timings)
        fastest = min(timings)
        total = sum(timings)

        print()
        print("Statistics")
        print("==========")
        print("")
        print(f"count: {count:.0f}")
        print(f" mean: {mean:.4f}s")
        print(f"  std: {stdev:.4f}s")
        print(f"  min: {fastest:.4f}s")
        print(f"  25%: {q1:.4f}s")
        print(f"  50%: {median:.4f}s")
        print(f"  75%: {q3:.4f}s")
        print(f"  max: {slowest:.4f}s")
        print(f"total: {total:.4f}s")

        # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range
        iqr = q3 - q1
        fast = q1 - 1.5 * iqr
        slow_threshold = q3 + 1.5 * iqr

        slow_tests = [
            (test, elapsed)
            for test, elapsed
            in StopwatchTestResult.timings.items()
            if elapsed >= slow_threshold
        ]

        if not slow_tests: return
        print()
        print("Outliers")
        print("========")
        print("These were particularly slow:")
        print()
        for test, elapsed in slow_tests:
            print(' ', test, f"[{elapsed:0.4f}s]")
```

To identify slow tests, you can analyze the obtained timing data for outliers. Usually, one would calculate the mean and a standard deviation and define outliers as all values beyond a certain threshold, such as +1.5 Standard deviations from the mean.

However, when collecting timing data, the distribution will be skewed, because responses can't be faster than 0 seconds and slow outliers will draw the distribution's  mean to the right in a long tail. Under these circumstances, mean and standard deviation can be difficult to interpret, thus the code uses a different approach to identify outliers.

Use `statistics.quantiles` from Python's statistics module (requires Python 3.8). This yields the 25%, 50% and 75% boundaries of the distribution. To identify outliers, you define the threshold as:

```
slow_threshold = q3 + 1.5 * iqr
```

You may want to finetune this formular for your purposes. The IQR is a reference for the dispersion of your distribution (interquartile range, q3 - q1). Instead of with q3, you might calculate the threshold starting from the median. You could reduce or increase the constant factor, which yould make the outlier detection more or less sensitive.

All together, this produces the following output:

```bash
...
test_bad_request (content.tests.test_image_upload_view.ImageUploadTests) [0.1159s]  ... ok
test_view_editor_can_access_create_page (edv.knowledgebase.tests.test_view_create_page.CreatePageTests) [3.5587s]  ... ok
test_admins_are_redirected_to_where_they_were_before (web.tests.test_view_login.LoginOfficialUser) [0.4595s]  ... ok
test_ldap_users_are_redirected_to_their_profile_pages (web.tests.test_view_login.LoginOfficialUser) [0.4522s]  ... ok
...

Statistics
==========

count: 708
 mean: 0.0222s
  std: 0.2177s
  min: 0.0000s
  25%: 0.0000s
  50%: 0.0000s
  75%: 0.0156s
  max: 4.5008s
total: 15.6883s

Outliers
========
These were particularly slow:

  test_account_view (account.tests.test_view_account.AccountViewTest) [0.0690s]
  test_headline_en (arbeitseinheit.tests.test_arbeitseinheit_page.ArbeitseinheitTest) [0.0846s]
  test_admins_see_admin_menu (arbeitseinheit.tests.test_arbeitseinheit_superuser.ArbeitseinheitTest) [0.1628s]
  test_editors_can_post_in_their_arbeitseinheit (arbeitseinheit.tests.test_view_create_news.CreateArticleViewTests) [0.0625s]
  test_bad_request (content.tests.test_image_upload_view.ImageUploadTests) [0.1159s]
...
```

Comment: Python 3.12 will introduce a `--durations` command line option, showing the N slowest test cases!

https://docs.python.org/3.12/whatsnew/3.12.html#unittest